# TYPO3 Persistence Repository thrown error on view rendering

Tags: repository, typo3, persistence, extbase, typo3-9.x

i did the TYPO3 9 Tutorial with my own properies

look here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/4-FirstExtension/Index.html

and i go this error:

```
Sat, 08 Dec 2018 21:34:32 +0100 [ALERT] request="e7d4fcf4b7814" component="TYPO3.CMS.Frontend.ContentObject.Exception.ProductionExceptionHandler": Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20181208213431d7e11182 - {"exception":"TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Storage\\Exception\\SqlErrorException: Table 'myvendor.tx_myplugin_domain_model_event' doesn't exist in \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Persistence\/Generic\/Storage\/Typo3DbBackend.php:473\nStack trace:\n#0 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Persistence\/Generic\/Backend.php(207): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Storage\\Typo3DbBackend->getObjectCountByQuery(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Query))\n#1 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Persistence\/Generic\/PersistenceManager.php(116): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Backend->getObjectCountByQuery(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Query))\n#2 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Persistence\/Generic\/QueryResult.php(143): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\PersistenceManager->getObjectCountByQuery(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Query))\n#3 [internal function]: TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\QueryResult->count()\n#4 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Utility\/DebuggerUtility.php(314): count(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\QueryResult))\n#5 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Utility\/DebuggerUtility.php(173): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Utility\\DebuggerUtility::renderHeader(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\QueryResult), 1, false, false)\n#6 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Utility\/DebuggerUtility.php(110): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Utility\\DebuggerUtility::renderObject(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\QueryResult), 1, false, false)\n#7 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Utility\/DebuggerUtility.php(558): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Utility\\DebuggerUtility::renderDump(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\QueryResult), 0, false, false)\n#8 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/fluid\/Classes\/ViewHelpers\/DebugViewHelper.php(86): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Utility\\DebuggerUtility::var_dump(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\QueryResult), 'Extbase Variabl...', 8, false, false, false, NULL, NULL)\n#9 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3temp\/var\/cache\/code\/fluid_template\/Event_action_list_aeb6f61cbefc302378b3d0832575b5c1b6300da6.php(61): TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\ViewHelpers\\DebugViewHelper::renderStatic(Array, Object(Closure), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext))\n#10 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/View\/AbstractTemplateView.php(186): Event_action_list_aeb6f61cbefc302378b3d0832575b5c1b6300da6->render(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext))\n#11 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3conf\/ext\/pluginname\/Classes\/Controller\/EventController.php(37): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\View\\AbstractTemplateView->render()\n#12 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Mvc\/Controller\/ActionController.php(318): myvendor\\pluginname\\Controller\\EventController->listAction()\n#13 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Mvc\/Controller\/ActionController.php(167): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\ActionController->callActionMethod()\n#14 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Mvc\/Dispatcher.php(73): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\ActionController->processRequest(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Web\\Request), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Web\\Response))\n#15 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Mvc\/Web\/FrontendRequestHandler.php(92): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Web\\Request), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Web\\Response))\n#16 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Core\/Bootstrap.php(172): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Web\\FrontendRequestHandler->handleRequest()\n#17 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Core\/Bootstrap.php(159): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Core\\Bootstrap->handleRequest()\n#18 [internal function]: TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Core\\Bootstrap->run('', Array)\n#19 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(5942): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#20 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/UserContentObject.php(41): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->callUserFunction('TYPO3\\\\CMS\\\\Extba...', Array, '')\n#21 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(811): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\UserContentObject->render(Array)\n#22 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(727): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->render(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\UserContentObject), Array)\n#23 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/fluid\/Classes\/ViewHelpers\/CObjectViewHelper.php(139): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->cObjGetSingle('USER', Array)\n#24 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3temp\/var\/cache\/code\/fluid_template\/Standard_action_List_3314f315fae063b9b607895602b0c08646b52663.php(68): TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\ViewHelpers\\CObjectViewHelper::renderStatic(Array, Object(Closure), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext))\n#25 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/View\/AbstractTemplateView.php(260): Standard_action_List_3314f315fae063b9b607895602b0c08646b52663->section_62bce9422ff2d14f69ab80a154510232fc8a9afd(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext))\n#26 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/ViewHelpers\/RenderViewHelper.php(143): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\View\\AbstractTemplateView->renderSection('Main', Array, true)\n#27 \/var\/www\/uel\/typo3temp\/var\/cache\/code\/fluid_template\/layout_Default_html_34e722a43ef4be367d8f376eda8027e71f36c01e.php(591): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\ViewHelpers\\RenderViewHelper::renderStatic(Array, Object(Closure), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext))\n#28 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/Core\/ViewHelper\/AbstractConditionViewHelper.php(85): layout_Default_html_34e722a43ef4be367d8f376eda8027e71f36c01e->{closure}()\n#29 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3temp\/var\/cache\/code\/fluid_template\/layout_Default_html_34e722a43ef4be367d8f376eda8027e71f36c01e.php(1018): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractConditionViewHelper::renderStatic(Array, Object(Closure), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext))\n#30 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/ViewHelpers\/SpacelessViewHelper.php(55): layout_Default_html_34e722a43ef4be367d8f376eda8027e71f36c01e->{closure}()\n#31 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3temp\/var\/cache\/code\/fluid_template\/layout_Default_html_34e722a43ef4be367d8f376eda8027e71f36c01e.php(1026): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\ViewHelpers\\SpacelessViewHelper::renderStatic(Array, Object(Closure), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext))\n#32 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/View\/AbstractTemplateView.php(201): layout_Default_html_34e722a43ef4be367d8f376eda8027e71f36c01e->render(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext))\n#33 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/FluidTemplateContentObject.php(358): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\View\\AbstractTemplateView->render()\n#34 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/FluidTemplateContentObject.php(107): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\FluidTemplateContentObject->renderFluidView()\n#35 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(811): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\FluidTemplateContentObject->render(Array)\n#36 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(727): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->render(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\FluidTemplateContentObject), Array)\n#37 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(709): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->cObjGetSingle('FLUIDTEMPLATE', Array, 'lib.contentElem...')\n#38 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/CaseContentObject.php(46): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->cObjGetSingle('FLUIDTEMPLATE', Array, 'list')\n#39 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(811): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\CaseContentObject->render(Array)\n#40 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(727): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->render(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\CaseContentObject), Array)\n#41 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(709): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->cObjGetSingle('CASE', Array, 'tt_content')\n#42 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/RecordsContentObject.php(117): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->cObjGetSingle('CASE', Array, '')\n#43 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(811): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\RecordsContentObject->render(Array)\n#44 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(727): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->render(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\RecordsContentObject), Array)\n#45 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3conf\/ext\/vhs\/Classes\/ViewHelpers\/Content\/AbstractContentViewHelper.php(236): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->cObjGetSingle('RECORDS', Array)\n#46 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3conf\/ext\/vhs\/Classes\/ViewHelpers\/Content\/AbstractContentViewHelper.php(203): FluidTYPO3\\Vhs\\ViewHelpers\\Content\\AbstractContentViewHelper::renderRecord(Array)\n#47 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3conf\/ext\/vhs\/Classes\/ViewHelpers\/Content\/AbstractContentViewHelper.php(110): FluidTYPO3\\Vhs\\ViewHelpers\\Content\\AbstractContentViewHelper->getRenderedRecords(Array)\n#48 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3conf\/ext\/vhs\/Classes\/ViewHelpers\/Content\/RenderViewHelper.php(49): FluidTYPO3\\Vhs\\ViewHelpers\\Content\\AbstractContentViewHelper->getContentRecords()\n#49 [internal function]: FluidTYPO3\\Vhs\\ViewHelpers\\Content\\RenderViewHelper->render()\n#50 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/Core\/ViewHelper\/AbstractViewHelper.php(262): call_user_func(Array)\n#51 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/Core\/ViewHelper\/AbstractViewHelper.php(250): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->callRenderMethod()\n#52 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/Core\/ViewHelper\/ViewHelperInvoker.php(79): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper->initializeArgumentsAndRender()\n#53 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/Core\/ViewHelper\/AbstractViewHelper.php(522): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\ViewHelperInvoker->invoke('FluidTYPO3\\\\Vhs\\\\...', Array, Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext), Object(Closure))\n#54 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3temp\/var\/cache\/code\/fluid_template\/Page_action_article_1c7b6e9d257399114dce1d3fe054382638918806.php(206): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\Core\\ViewHelper\\AbstractViewHelper::renderStatic(Array, Object(Closure), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext))\n#55 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/View\/AbstractTemplateView.php(260): Page_action_article_1c7b6e9d257399114dce1d3fe054382638918806->section_62bce9422ff2d14f69ab80a154510232fc8a9afd(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext))\n#56 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/ViewHelpers\/RenderViewHelper.php(143): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\View\\AbstractTemplateView->renderSection('Main', Array, false)\n#57 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3temp\/var\/cache\/code\/fluid_template\/layout_Page_html_2c66b863254044f5e1ce47ac05cd45f78ae0b7d1.php(130): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\ViewHelpers\\RenderViewHelper::renderStatic(Array, Object(Closure), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext))\n#58 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/vendor\/typo3fluid\/fluid\/src\/View\/AbstractTemplateView.php(201): layout_Page_html_2c66b863254044f5e1ce47ac05cd45f78ae0b7d1->render(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\Core\\Rendering\\RenderingContext))\n#59 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3conf\/ext\/flux\/Classes\/Controller\/AbstractFluxController.php(333): TYPO3Fluid\\Fluid\\View\\AbstractTemplateView->render()\n#60 \/var\/www\/url\/typo3conf\/ext\/flux\/Classes\/Controller\/AbstractFluxController.php(307): FluidTYPO3\\Flux\\Controller\\AbstractFluxController->performSubRendering('tx_tablename...', 'Page', 'article', 'tx_tablename...')\n#61 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Mvc\/Controller\/ActionController.php(318): FluidTYPO3\\Flux\\Controller\\AbstractFluxController->renderAction()\n#62 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Mvc\/Controller\/ActionController.php(167): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\ActionController->callActionMethod()\n#63 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Mvc\/Dispatcher.php(73): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Controller\\ActionController->processRequest(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Web\\Request), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Web\\Response))\n#64 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Mvc\/Web\/FrontendRequestHandler.php(92): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Web\\Request), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Web\\Response))\n#65 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Core\/Bootstrap.php(172): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Mvc\\Web\\FrontendRequestHandler->handleRequest()\n#66 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/extbase\/Classes\/Core\/Bootstrap.php(159): TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Core\\Bootstrap->handleRequest()\n#67 [internal function]: TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Core\\Bootstrap->run('', Array)\n#68 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(5942): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)\n#69 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/UserContentObject.php(41): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->callUserFunction('TYPO3\\\\CMS\\\\Extba...', Array, '')\n#70 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(811): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\UserContentObject->render(Array)\n#71 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(727): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->render(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\UserContentObject), Array)\n#72 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/ContentObject\/ContentObjectRenderer.php(673): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->cObjGetSingle('USER', Array, '5')\n#73 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Http\/RequestHandler.php(251): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer->cObjGet(Array)\n#74 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Http\/RequestHandler.php(273): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Http\\RequestHandler->generatePageContent(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Controller\\TypoScriptFrontendController))\n#75 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Http\/RequestHandler.php(168): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Http\\RequestHandler->generatePageContentWithHeader(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Controller\\TypoScriptFrontendController), NULL)\n#76 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/OutputCompression.php(46): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Http\\RequestHandler->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#77 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\OutputCompression->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Http\\RequestHandler))\n#78 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/adminpanel\/Classes\/Middleware\/AdminPanelDataPersister.php(44): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#79 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Adminpanel\\Middleware\\AdminPanelDataPersister->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#80 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/adminpanel\/Classes\/Middleware\/AdminPanelRenderer.php(46): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#81 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Adminpanel\\Middleware\\AdminPanelRenderer->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#82 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/ContentLengthResponseHeader.php(45): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#83 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\ContentLengthResponseHeader->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#84 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/ShortcutAndMountPointRedirect.php(65): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#85 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\ShortcutAndMountPointRedirect->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#86 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/PrepareTypoScriptFrontendRendering.php(118): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#87 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\PrepareTypoScriptFrontendRendering->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#88 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/PageArgumentValidator.php(86): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#89 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\PageArgumentValidator->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#90 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/MaintenanceMode.php(53): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#91 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\MaintenanceMode->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#92 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/PageResolver.php(162): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#93 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\PageResolver->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#94 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/redirects\/Classes\/Http\/Middleware\/RedirectHandler.php(70): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#95 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Redirects\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectHandler->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#96 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/StaticRouteResolver.php(66): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#97 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\StaticRouteResolver->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#98 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/SiteBaseRedirectResolver.php(80): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#99 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\SiteBaseRedirectResolver->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#100 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/adminpanel\/Classes\/Middleware\/AdminPanelInitiator.php(58): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#101 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Adminpanel\\Middleware\\AdminPanelInitiator->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#102 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/SiteResolver.php(68): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#103 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\SiteResolver->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#104 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/adminpanel\/Classes\/Middleware\/SqlLogging.php(49): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#105 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Adminpanel\\Middleware\\SqlLogging->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#106 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/BackendUserAuthenticator.php(95): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#107 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\BackendUserAuthenticator->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#108 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/FrontendUserAuthenticator.php(79): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#109 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\FrontendUserAuthenticator->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#110 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/TypoScriptFrontendInitialization.php(91): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#111 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\TypoScriptFrontendInitialization->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#112 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/EidHandler.php(50): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#113 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\EidHandler->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#114 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/PreprocessRequestHook.php(57): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#115 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\PreprocessRequestHook->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#116 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Middleware\/NormalizedParamsAttribute.php(58): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#117 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Middleware\\NormalizedParamsAttribute->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#118 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Middleware\/TimeTrackerInitialization.php(49): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#119 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(138): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Middleware\\TimeTrackerInitialization->process(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest), Object(class@anonymous))\n#120 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(67): class@anonymous->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#121 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/AbstractApplication.php(98): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#122 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/frontend\/Classes\/Http\/Application.php(69): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\AbstractApplication->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#123 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/typo3\/sysext\/core\/Classes\/Http\/AbstractApplication.php(110): TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Http\\Application->handle(Object(TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\ServerRequest))\n#124 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/index.php(24): TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Http\\AbstractApplication->run()\n#125 \/var\/www\/typo3\/typo3_src-9.5.1\/index.php(25): {closure}()\n#126 {main}"}
```

if i rendered the view with the variables from the repository/databse (?).

I tried so many things to solve this and i dont find anything in web.

I hope anyone can help me here...

my repository code:

```
namespace myvendor\EventPlugin\Domain\Repository;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository;

/**
 * Class ProductRepository
 *
 * @package myvendor\EventPlugin\Domain\Repository
 */
class EventRepository extends Repository {

}
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
   <?php

namespace myvendor\EventPlugin\Controller;

use Myvendor\EventPlugin\Domain\Repository\EventRepository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;

/**
 * Class EventController
 *
 * @package myvendor\EventPlugin\Controller
 */
class EventController extends ActionController {

    /**
     * @var EventRepository
     */
    private $eventRepository;

    /**
     * Inject the event repository
     *
     * @param \myvendor\EventPlugin\Domain\Repository\EventRepository $eventRepository
     */
    public function injectEventRepository(EventRepository $eventRepository) {
        $this->eventRepository = $eventRepository;
    }

    /**
     * List Action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function listAction() {
        $events = $this->eventRepository->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('events', $events);
        return $this->view->render();
    }

}
```

the error occures when i call this in my view:

```
<f:debug>{events}</f:debug>
```

### Notice: i renamed the vendor name and pluginname here just for anonymization

Comment: Table 'myvendor.tx_myplugin_domain_model_event' doesn't exist

There is something very wrong in some configuration I guess.

Above you have the extension name "EventPlugin" which means the extension key is "event_plugin" and the database table should therefore begin with `tx_eventplugin_domain_model*`.

Please update the description to include the ext_typoscript_setup.txt file from the extension's root directory.

Comment: @MKlein I renamed the vendor and pluginname here because i cant give the name of my company and our customers here :-D

Comment: Did you deinstall and reinstall the extension to create new caches? Does table exists in database?

Comment: @HeinzSchilling yes, the table exist and i refreshed table indexes, a reinstall of the extension doesnt't work

Comment: What do you mean with "a reinstall of the extension doesn't work"? If you got errors by installing the extension you have to solve this first.

Comment: @HeinzSchilling i mean, that this doesnt resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your controller a little bit and fix some case sensitive namespaces.

```
<?php
namespace Myvendor\EventPlugin\Controller;

use Myvendor\EventPlugin\Domain\Repository\EventRepository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;

/**
 * Class EventController
 *
 * @package Myvendor\EventPlugin\Controller
 */
class EventController extends ActionController {

    /**
     * @var EventRepository
     * @inject
     */
    private $eventRepository;

    /**
     * List Action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function listAction() {
        $events = $this->eventRepository->findAll();
        $this->view->assign('events', $events);
    }

}
```

But I think your problem will be solved be deinstall and reinstall your extension.

Comment: why you removed the repository injection?

Comment: Your solution throw an error:

     
    Oops, an error occurred!
    Call to a member function findAll() on null

Comment: the `@inject` property works as well but should be avoided and is deprecated with 9. to make it work, clear all caches in Install Tool

Comment: @GeorgRinger thank you for your answer, but why is it in the typo3 9 documentation?

I followed your instroductions and it doesn't work

Comment: @GeorgRinger off topic: How to inject repository after TYPO3 9?

Comment: by using the injectMethod